# Integral of $\sin(ax+b)\cos(ax+b)$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

$\displaystyle\int \sin(ax+b)\cos(ax+b) \, dx$ is giving me two answers;

1. $\dfrac{1}{2a}\sin^2(ax+b)+C$
2. negative of    $\dfrac{1}{4a}\cos2(ax+b) +C$

Are these two results the same? Can you please prove it? Thank you

Comment: Please mention if you would like to know how I got the two results

Answer (score 2):

They are same. Just use the formula
$$\cos 2A = 1 - 2 \sin^2 A$$

Answer (score 1):

They are the same because you add a fixed constant to an arbitrary constant you should get back an arbitrary constant.